# How can I reset two factor authentication on 2.3.5?

Tags: magento2.3.5

I am using Magento 2.3.5. I need to move my 2fa to a new phone. When looking at the docs- https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/stores/security-two-factor-authentication-manage.html (these docs are also for 2.4) it talks about a box on the left panel. I do not have that box and I am admin. Is it different for 2.3.5?

Answer (score 2):

**Reset 2FA Info**

```
bin/magento msp:security:tfa:reset --help

Description:
  Reset configuration for one user

Usage:
  msp:security:tfa:reset <user> <provider>

Arguments:
  user                  Username
  provider              Provider code
```

**List all providers**

```
bin/magento msp:security:tfa:providers

google: Google Authenticator
duo_security: Duo Security
authy: Authy
u2fkey: U2F (Yubikey and others)
```

**Reset 2FA**

```
bin/magento msp:security:tfa:reset YourAdminUsername google
```

This command will reset your admin user values in the database table `msp_tfa_user_config`:

```
MariaDB [magento]> SELECT * FROM msp_tfa_user_config WHERE user_id = 299 \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
msp_tfa_user_config_id: 272
               user_id: 299
     encoded_providers: []
        encoded_config: 0:3:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      default_provider: google
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

https://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento2-reset-admin-2fa-two-factor-authentication/

Answer (score 1):

Reset authenticator per account
If you need to manually reset a single user configuration, enter the following command. It restarts configuration and 2FA subscription for the user account.

bin/magento msp:security:tfa:reset